# Ripple Emulator Works - Android phone does not

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ripple, rotatetransform

So I've created a game using PhoneGap and I've tested it on ripple emulator and it works beautifully.
Unfortunately when I transfer the apk onto my phone and test it out, only some of the elements work correctly while others such as image.rotate() do not.

Any ideas?